# When does a 'loan word' cease to be defined as such?

Tags: word-usage, loanwords

At what point does a 'loan word' cease to be defined as such? Does it depend on for how long, or frequently a word has been used?

Comment: When everybody has forgotten that it wasn't originally part of the language?

Comment: Being a loan word is part of its etymology. That's history; it doesn't change. Once a loan word, always a loan word.

Comment: I think John Lawler highlights a key point, but one which has interesting implications. If every word in English derived from French, Latin, Greek or Sanskrit (for example) is a loan word, does the term cease to have any usefulness? I'd go along with Weather Vane's definition, even if this is more subjective, that it's to do when when we feel a word has been assimilated. When someone says 'he's got cojones' you register the use of a loan word, but 'he's really brave' ('brave' being a French loanword from the 1500's) doesn't sound borrowed.

Comment: This should perhaps be closed as POB. If someone set up a usage panel and submitted various sensible candidates, we'd all be amazed if all the panel agreed on every word's status.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, that the boundaries of the meaning of a particular word are not precise (as is the case with almost all words in everyday use) does not mean that its meaning is up for grabs, and that nothing definite can be said about it. We'd all be amazed if a usage panel agreed in **every** instance on whether something is a chair, but that wouldn't make that the meaning of *chair* 'POB'.

Comment: @jsw29 There is a parallel. Some candidate sentences are considered acceptable by some but not all members of respected usage panels ([Quirk & Svartvik](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/english-usage/about/svartvik.htm), I believe, demonstrated this totally expected result). Some candidate neologisms are accepted as words by some members of proficient usage panels. And some candidates of some usage panels would class word X as a loanword, others not. This question has an answer 'primarily opinion-based'. As Tuffy spells out.

Answer (score 4):

*Loanword* is defined in the following way in Merriam Webster:-

> a word taken from another language and **at least** partly naturalized

On that definition, there would be no point at which, say, the word *naïve* (the feminine form of the French word *naïf*) can cease to be a loan word.  Even when it is fully naturalised, it remains **at least partly** naturalised.

Cambridge English defines it thus:

> a word taken from one language and used in another

This definition is even more permissive than the American one.

It leaves some uncomfortable implications to this definitions, which, I think, have some force.

Many are surprised to learn that the humble *bungalow* is a loanword from India, as are our pyjamas.  On the above definitions, they must be regarded as loanwords, like the good old double decker *bus* (the vehicle for everybody, for which the Latin is *omni**bus***).

And what about the language of science, brought in without charge from ancient Greek (*philosophy*, *rhetoric*, *oligarchy*...)?  Are these not loanwords, even though they come from a different language?  Or do we give Greek and Latin vocabulary special immigration status as part of the Anglo-European linguistic empire?

So I am inclined to agree with those who have suggested that at some point we cease to think of words like café a foreign and drop the acute accent.  So *tea*, *chess* and *etcetera* will be fully native English (of whichever national variety), with a nonetheless rich and fascinating ancestry.

Meanwhile, from the other side of the loan, other languages look (at least to us) a bit less well integrated.  So in modern Greek you watch television relaxing in *to livingkrum*.  You might have a sail in *to giot* (unless you are willing to use the more windy *skaphos anapsychis* - literally *vessel of wind)*.  Your trousers are Italian *pantalonia*, and your suit is a French *kostoumi*.  If you want a cup for your tea, you ask for a Turkish *flintzani*.

We should probably exclude from the family of loanwords new the Greco-Roman language of science and law, as well as key technological inventions like the internet, computer etc.  Languages handle these with varying preference given to convenience, inventiveness and national or ethnic pride.

A tighter definition of *loanword* might be helpful.  Or it might take us round in circles.

Comment: For this looping and hooping bit at the end, don't you mean "takes us round in rings" — or perhaps more archaically or dialectically,  "takes us round in trendles/trindles/trundles"? After all, *circle* is itself a borrowed loanword. :)

Comment: @tchrist That brings us to another aspect of English (and other languages within the former Holy Roman Empire (and its Roman ancestor.  In Britain, especially, Latin actually preceded the arrival of Saxons and Angles, and the language they brought with them.  It remained the language of Christian worship and scholarship.  So ‘loan’ is rather out of place.  In any case, ‘loan’ is an odd word to use.  No one will ‘give it back’.  But that’s the ‘loanword’ we have, and it is, at least, of good Anglo-Saxon stock.  The use of loanwords varies in its origins: empire, class, ostentation, tourism....

Comment: @tchrist CONT..  An example of ostentation is the pronunciation by film critics of the word ‘homage’ with a French accent as ‘omarge’.  It is, I suppose an acknowledgement of the French status in the history of film; but it is also showing off.

Comment: I've never heard an R in *homage*.

Comment: @tchrist You have to listen to film buffs, or should I say aficionados?

Comment: What’s the IPA for this ‹R› you've put there? Does it mean ❶ the voiced  postalveolar approximant **[ɹ̠]** [like in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects), ❷ the voiced uvular fricative **[ʁ]** [like in French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guttural_R#French), or ❸ the voiced alveolar tap **[ɾ]** [like in Scottish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects#cite_note-r-13) or Italian? Real French of course has ❹ **[omɑʒ]** — *et pas ton* ✻[omɑʁʒ], *qui n’existe point, tu sais.* 

Comment: Well, you have succeeded in losing me, uninitiated as I am into the mysteries of phonetics.

Comment: @tchrist It's presumably the way non-rhotic BrE speakers write out a long a, which in AmE might be written 'ah' as in 'o- mahzh'.

Comment: A further category of loanword could be a form of 'partially adapted loanword', there are many of these in Spanish - 'basket' for basketball, 'loft' for studio, 'freaki' for nerd. Perhaps there are similar examples in English where a word from another language has changed its meaning or part of speech.

Comment: @DanielWatts Yes.  Nd this is not uncommon.  Also there can be words which remain the same but change their use to a greater or lesser extent.

Comment: @Mitch Hadding psileant leitters wreally conphushes miegh.

Comment: An interesting phenomenon I have found.  I thought that the English use of ‘déjà-vu’ had shifted from referring just to the psychological illusion that what I am observing is an exact repetition of something I have experienced before to what is now regularly applied to actual repetitions.  I was about to cite this change of use as confined to English, and that therefore the expression was fully English.  Then I checked Larousse:  the same thing has happened in French also!  What I do not know is whether this is a co-incidence.

Comment: @Tuffy it probably isn't. English is like sand: it's rough and coarse and gets everywhere

Comment: @No Name  I love that:  thank you.

Comment: The dictionary definitions of *loanword* ate indeed far too broad. The actual use of the word is probably guided by the metaphor of a loan that it embodies: as long as we perceive the word to be the 'property' of another language, which we just happen to be 'borrowing', it's a loanword; once we get to fully 'own' it (by something that, in the world of literal property, would be called adverse possession), it isn't a loanword any more.